# 「人はだれしもが、…」and「人はみんな、…」

Tags: grammar

The first sentence is from a book synopsis, while the second one is from the preface.

> ひとはだれしもが、心に灯台を持っている
> ひとは皆、心の灯台を持っている

They both seem to mean the same thing.

1. Are there two subjects in these sentences (ひと and みんな)?
2. Is it optional to use が after だれしも or みんな? I mean, is it correct to use it?
3. What's the meaning of が in this specific case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there two subjects in these sentences (ひと and みんな)?

No, in your second example, this みな is working as an adverb. It's working like adverbial *all* as in "We are *all* mortal".

> Is it optional to use が after だれしも or みんな? I mean, is it correct to use it?

It depends.

1. ひとはだれしも...: OK (だれしも is adverbial)
2. ひとは皆...: OK (皆 is adverbial)
3. ひとはだれしもが...: OK
4. ひとは皆が...: NG

<sub>Sentence 3 is OK but Sentence 4 is not, and it's hard for me to explain why. I may be wrong, but it may be due to a restriction of the `AはBが` construction (aka "double-subject"). When you say `AはBが`, B has to be a part of A. だれしも ("whoever") can be understood as a subset of ひと ("people"), but みな ("everyone") is not a subset of ひと ("people").</sub>

> What's the meaning of が in this specific case?

The subject marker.